# integrating d3.js graph into angularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

i am getting problem while converting d3.js into angularJS so i have core d3.js code
i.e.

app.js

```
 var margin = {top: 20, right: 120, bottom: 20, left: 120},
width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left,
height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var i = 0;

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
.size([height, width]);

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
.projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; });

 var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  // load the external data
  d3.json("treeData.json", function(error, treeData) {
  root = treeData[0];
  update(root);
  });

  function update(source) {

// Compute the new tree layout.
var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
    links = tree.links(nodes);

// Normalize for fixed-depth.
nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * 180; });

// Declare the nodes…
var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
    .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

// Enter the nodes.
var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; });

nodeEnter.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 10)
    .style("fill", "#fff");

nodeEnter.append("text")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
        return d.children || d._children ? -13 : 13; })
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
        return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
    .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
    .style("fill-opacity", 1);

// Declare the links…
var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
    .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

// Enter the links.
link.enter().insert("path", "g")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr("d", diagonal);
```

}

index.html

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html ng-app="d3DemoApp">
 <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<title>Collapsible Tree Example</title>

<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body ng-controller="AppCtrl">

<!-- load the d3.js library -->
 <script src="treeData.json"></script>
 <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

 <script src="app.js"></script>


 </body>
 </html>
```

style.css

```
  .node circle {
fill: #fff;
stroke: steelblue;
stroke-width: 3px;
}

.node text { font: 12px sans-serif; }

 .link {
fill: none;
stroke: #ccc;
stroke-width: 2px;
 }
```

treeData.json

```
  [
{
    "name": "Top Level",
    "parent": "null",
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "Level 2: A",
            "parent": "Top Level",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "Son of A",
                    "parent": "Level 2: A"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Daughter of A",
                    "parent": "Level 2: A"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Level 2: B",
            "parent": "Top Level"
        }
       ]
     }
   ]
```

so please anyone help me to convert thease code into angularjs
so it will help me for creating another graph in angularJS

thanks,

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: write those code in controller or call from controller and change d3.select("body") to something that inside angular template, it will just work.